# what would be the base optimal throttle and seed for an application using monkey test?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, monkey, android-firmware

I am running monkey test on my application using following command

`adb shell monkey -p com.droigons.mygps --throttle 1000 -s 1000 -v 500000 > test.txt`

what would be the base optimal throttle and seed for an application?

Answer (score 1):

I use 120 it is optimal i think

Answer (score 0):

First, you must know monkey is aim to stress test. From my experience, it is difficult to reproduce the crash even using the -s option with same seed. 
 Why we use  --throttle option? I think it is used to minimize the impact of input event send by monkey. If you use appropriate --throttle value, it is helpful to reproduce the crash. ie. 600 milliseconds.

Events:
-s    Seed value for pseudo-random number generator. If you re-run the Monkey with the same seed value, it will generate the same sequence of events.

--throttle    Inserts a fixed delay between events. You can use this option to slow down the Monkey. If not specified, there is no delay and the events are generated as rapidly as possible.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html